# Magento 2.2 sidebar and additional sidebar issue

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, sidebar

My Magento installation behaves weird. Sidebar main and sidebar additional do not display on the same level as column main as it should but Magento layout engine moves them under the column main. I tried everything and so far I do not know why.

**Wrong layout**

[image: Sidebars wrong]

**Correct layout**

[image: Sidebars correct]

**My corresponding layout `xml` is**

```
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar-products" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar-products</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar-partners" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar-partners</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
    <move element="content.aside" destination="page.bottom.container" as="related_stuff"/>
    <move element="product.info" destination="content" after="product.info.media" />
    <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" after="-" />
</body>
```

I have searched in my theme folder for layout updates or any files containing **"sidebar"** but nothing has come up.

Any ideas where I should check where the layout engine gets these wrong instructions?

Oh, And I also have tried with my own **`empty.xml`** but no success :(

Comment: First check are you using layout type as `layout="2columns-left"` or `layout="2columns-right"`or not in=f no than first make it like this in your xml files & check it into your backend also into the design section for the design changes!

Comment: I'm using 2columns-right.

Comment: Oh, and I discovered that when I open the product from the product list the engine renders the page with the wrong layot. When I open the product from the shopping cart by clicking the "Edit" link (pencil icon) the page renders correctly. Both pages use the same layout xml (the snippet above) catalog_product_view.xml from Magento_Catalog

Comment: Validate you HTML, I had the same issue, then found out there was a div tag without a closing div. Adding </div> fix the issue in my case. Remember, Chrome try to be smart and close divs for you, which will mess up the page structure.